# Canon printer LBP6020

Tags: printing, canon

Could anyone confirm me if this printer is supported and it is working under ubuntu (any version)?

On [their website](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/printers/Laser/i-SENSYS_LBP6020B.aspx?type=download&page=1) it says it doesn't support linux (is missing from OS list I mean).

Comment: This is your best bet: https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon-stable it is a package for canon printers. Almost all canon printers we have here can be installed with that package. Daily version here: https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon-trunk  LBP6200D is supported: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrintersCanon You could try that device when searching for the printer in "printers"

Comment: Is your printer working now? If you found an answer to your question, please post it as answer.

Comment: Yes, my printer is working flawlessly now with a bit of trouble at installing.

As an advice for anyone who wants to install it on x64 machines, first u have to install all the dependency packages for x86 version, and then install the x64 .deb/rpm packages.